# Does Requery for Android autogenerate classes?

Tags: android, android-database

I have several Model objects (CateogryModel, MenuModel, OrderModel etc). I'm now trying to implement a  local database and decided on using Requery.

In their docs, they mention:

> getter, setters, equals & hashCode automatically generated into Person.java

So let's assume I already have Person.java with the following:

```
private class Person
{
    int id;
    String name;

    //getter setter
}
```

and I change it to:

```
@Entity
abstract class Person
{
    @Key @Generated
    int id;

    @Index("name")
    String name;
}
```

What will happen? Where will my getters and setters go? Will requery generate a new class when I build the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the project, Requery will generate the PersonEntity class in app/build/generated folder with same package name as Person class.

from API docs:

```
 /**
 * @return the desired Entity name for the type. This class will be generated by the processor
 * in the same package as the type the annotation is placed on. This name is also used as the
 * table name unless a {@link Table} attribute is specified with a different name.
 * Defaults to empty, the processor will remove "Abstract" prefix from the class name if it
 * exists.
 */
```

Comment: And what if I refactor Person to AbstractPerson? Will the generated class be named Person?

Comment: Yes. Correct. "Abtract" prefix will be removed.

Comment: Can I directly use @Entity inside my normal class (private class Person)? I don't want to modify too much code.

Comment: It is not possible as the generated class extends the class you define. For example PersonEntity extends Person. So if the Person class is private. you cannot extends it from PersonEntity class (access is denied)